# How to fix: OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]

3 month project about to  be scrapped because of this.

Makes zero sense  why this does not work.
I've tried rebooting etc.  I have a sample project with the same versions of Forms etc which works.
I've tried taking the AppMapViewModelBase from  that project into mine and the error still there.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Prism;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace bla.Infrastructure {


public abstract class AppMapViewModelBase : BindableBase, IInitialize, INavigationAware, IConfirmNavigation, IDestructible
{

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => _isBusy;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isBusy, value);
    }

    private int _cartItemCount;

    public int CartItemCount
    {
        // get => _password;
        get { return App.Current.CartItemCount; }
        //set => SetProperty(ref _cartItemCount, value);
        set
        {
            _cartItemCount = value;
            App.Current.CartItemCount = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    const string RootUriPrependText = "/";
    DelegateCommand<string> _navigateAbsoluteCommand;
    DelegateCommand<string> _navigateCommand;
    DelegateCommand<string> _navigateModalCommand;
    DelegateCommand<string> _navigateNonModalCommand;

    private bool _isNotConnected;
    public bool IsNotConnected
    {
        get
        {
            if (DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return _isNotConnected;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isNotConnected, value);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the navigate absolute command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The navigate absolute command.</value>
    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateAbsoluteCommand => _navigateAbsoluteCommand ?? (_navigateAbsoluteCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(NavigateAbsoluteCommandExecute, CanNavigateAbsoluteCommandExecute));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the navigate command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The navigate command.</value>
    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand => _navigateCommand ?? (_navigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(NavigateCommandExecute, CanNavigateCommandExecute));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the navigate modal command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The navigate modal command.</value>
    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateModalCommand => _navigateModalCommand ?? (_navigateModalCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(NavigateModalCommandExecute, CanNavigateModalCommandExecute));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the navigate non modal command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The navigate non modal command.</value>
    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateNonModalCommand => _navigateNonModalCommand ?? (_navigateNonModalCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(NavigateNonModalCommandExecute, CanNavigateNonModalCommandExecute));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the navigation service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The navigation service.</value>
    protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AppMapViewModelBase"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigationService">The navigation service.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">navigationService</exception>
    protected AppMapViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        if (navigationService == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(navigationService));
        }
        this.NavigationService = navigationService;

        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
        IsNotConnected = Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet;

     
    }



    void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            //NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/NoInternet");
        }

       IsNotConnected = e.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance accepts being navigated away from.  This method is invoked by Prism before a navigation operation and is a member of IConfirmNavigation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameters">The navigation parameters.</param>
    /// <returns><c>True</c> if navigation can continue, <c>False</c> if navigation is not allowed to continue</returns>
    public virtual bool CanNavigate(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can execute the NavigateAbsoluteCommand.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if this instance can execute NavigateAbsoluteCommand; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    protected virtual bool CanNavigateAbsoluteCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can execute the NavigateAbsoluteCommand.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if this instance can execute NavigateAbsoluteCommand; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    protected virtual bool CanNavigateCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can execute the NavigateModalCommand.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if this instance can execute NavigateModalCommand; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    protected virtual bool CanNavigateModalCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can execute the NavigateNonModalCommand.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if this instance can execute NavigateNonModalCommand; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    protected virtual bool CanNavigateNonModalCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <p>Invoked by Prism Navigation when the instance is removed from the navigation stack.</p>
    /// <p>Deriving class can override and perform any required clean up.</p>
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Destroy()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigates to the uri after creating a new navigation root. (Effectively replacing the Application MainPage.)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri text.</param>
    /// <returns>Task.</returns>
    protected virtual async void NavigateAbsoluteCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        if (!CanNavigateAbsoluteCommandExecute(uri))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!uri.StartsWith(RootUriPrependText))
        {
            uri = string.Concat(RootUriPrependText, uri);
        }
        await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(uri, null, false,false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigates to the uri.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri text.</param>
    /// <returns>Task.</returns>
    protected virtual async void NavigateCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        if (!CanNavigateCommandExecute(uri))
        {
            return;
        }
        await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(uri);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigates to the uri using a Modal navigation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri text.</param>
    /// <returns>Task.</returns>
    protected virtual async void NavigateModalCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        if (!CanNavigateModalCommandExecute(uri))
        {
            return;
        }
        await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(uri,null, useModalNavigation: true,animated:false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigates to the uri using Non-Modal navigation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri text.</param>
    /// <returns>Task.</returns>
    protected virtual async void NavigateNonModalCommandExecute(string uri)
    {
        if (!CanNavigateNonModalCommandExecute(uri))
        {
            return;
        }
        await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(uri,null, useModalNavigation: false,false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked by Prism immediately after the ViewModel has been created.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters.</param>
    public virtual void InitializeAsync(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked by Prism after navigating away from viewmodel's page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters.</param>
    public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked by Prism after navigating to the viewmodel's page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters.</param>
    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

   

    public virtual void  Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
         
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the method is wrong.
The prefix `I` is missing before `NavigationParameters`, because `OnNavigatedFrom` expects an interface of type `INavigationParameters` as parameter:

Change `NavigationParameters` to `INavigationParameters`

```
     public override void OnNavigatedFrom (INavigationParameters navigationParameters)
     {
     }
```

Comment: You should add that this has absolutely nothing to do with anything Prism-related, it's all user code.